# Hardware for iPhone 2d games development

Tags: iphone

Do I need the cutting edge MacBook Pro or iMac for 2D games development?

Would a iPod touch (with Wi-Fi support) do instead of a full-fledge iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any modern Mac that runs Snow Leopard is adequate for 2D games development.

There's nothing particularly hardware intensive about 2D game development for iOS. The most intensive things you will be doing is compiling your code and running the emulator and debugging tools - my Mac Mini did all of these tasks with ease.

The iPod touch is sufficient for testing games destined for the iPhone.
The devices have the same screen resolutions, CPUs and iOS versions.
The latest iPod Touch does have less memory than the latest iPhone (256MB as opposed to 512MB) so this is something you should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Well we're using Mac Minis for the iPhone development (kinda old macs, Core 2 Duo 2Ghz, 2GB RAM, integrated graphics) and it's fine. OS: Leopard / Snow Leopard.